# is there any way to import CRM solution to multiple orgs with one task on Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, dynamics-crm, azure-pipelines, crm

Is there any way to import CRM solution to multiple orgs using one task or script on azure release pipelines.

I have to import CRM solution to too many orgs. Currently I have tried Import CRM Solution 2016 and MSCRM import solution task, both these support only one org and i have to make clones for multiple orgs.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to import CRM solution to multiple orgs with one task
>   on Azure Pipelines?

For this issue, I am afraid that it is currently not supported in the azure pipeline to import a solution to multiple target organizations in one task.

You can specify only one organization, even if you deploy using scripts. You can refer to following part of the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/deploy-packages-using-package-deployer-windows-powershell).

> If you have multiple organizations on your server, select **an**
>   organization to connect to.

Deploying crm package using visual studio can also only select one organization.

[image]

So for now, you can only import multiple tasks by adding multiple tasks in azure devops. You can also submit your feature [request](https://github.com/chamindac/vsts.release.task.crm-2016/issues) in the github repo for the extension.